# Value Error: Need more than 0 values to unpack

Tags: python

I try to run the following Python script and I get the following error. Can anyone please help? Thanks.

```
sP=['','','']
vP=['','','']
for rows in range(len(data)):     # Repeat The Process for each set of data
    print rows
    # Read from the Data file :##
    sP[0], sP[1], sP[2], vP[0], vP[1], vP[2], SpotType, SpotDim, Overlap, Length, PressureMagnitude, PressureFWHM, FieldType, TempPressPro = data[rows][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]

    ##: Read Model and Part Name :##
    if ModelNm == '1st':
        ModelNm = mdb.models.keys(0)[0]             #: First Model Name

    if len(data[rows])==14:
        print 'No Extras'
        ##: Enter data into Row Function :##
        UStepLen, NewUltimateStep = LPRowBuilder(ModelNm,PartNm,sP,vP,SpotType.strip(), SpotDim, Overlap, Length, PressureMagnitude, PressureFWHM, FieldType.strip(), TempPressPro.strip())

    else:
        print 'Extras'
        Optionals=data[rows][14:]

        def dctBuild(X): return [X.split('=')[0].strip(), X.split('=')[1].strip()]

        Optionals=dict(map(dctBuild,data[rows][14:]))
        ##: Enter data into Row Function :##

        UStepLen, NewUltimateStep = LPRowBuilder(ModelNm,PartNm,sP,vP,SpotType.strip(), SpotDim, Overlap, Length, PressureMagnitude, PressureFWHM, FieldType.strip(), TempPressPro.strip(), **Optionals)

    if ModelNm == '1st':
        ModelNm = mdb.models.keys(0)[0]

if NewUltimateStep != 'Yes':
    prevStepTime = mdb.models[ModelNm].steps['Load-Step'].timePeriod
    mdb.models[ModelNm].steps['Load-Step'].setValues(timePeriod=prevStepTime+UStepLen)
    del mdb.models[ModelNm].steps['Post-Load']
```

Error:

> sP[0], sP[1], sP[2], vP[0], vP[1], vP[2], SpotType, SpotDim, Overlap, Length, PressureMagnitude, PressureFWHM, FieldType, TempPressPro = data[rows][:14]
>
> ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Comment: The code shown in your exception message and the code you show above it are not the same. Do you really have all the `[]`'s you've shown, or is that something you've tried adding later to fix the issue? What is `data[rows]` for the row that causes the error?

Answer (score 1):

Your length of variable name, assigning values not match. Use comma between [ ]:

```
sP[0], sP[1], sP[2], vP[0], vP[1], vP[2], SpotType, SpotDim, Overlap, Length, PressureMagnitude, PressureFWHM, FieldType, TempPressPro = data[rows], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Like if defined two variable with no value. It gives the error:

```
a,b = []
# raise ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Because It is expect 2 values for a,b

```
a,b = [1,2]
# It is work Fine
```